# Newbee Drools chained list filtering

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I'm pretty new to Drools but wanted to use it for a case I need to solve.

Basically my rules need to do the following:

- Filter a given initial read-only (complete) list of locations based on a given distance to a persons current position
- Create a new list with locations within that given distance radius
- Hand over that new list to the next rule
- Filter the new locations list based on a specific title
- Create a new list with locations (now filtered by distance and title)

So, I want to chain several rules ... first do that, create new list with results, use new list in next rule, perform further filtering on it, create new list with even more filtered elements ... and so on ...

Honestly, as mentioned before, I'm absolutely stuck and thought I could get some adivsory ...

My initial rule, I came up with, looks like this:

```
package com.acme.rulesets
import com.acme.domain.TopLocation
import com.acme.domain.Person
import com.acme.storage.LocationContainer
import com.acme.helper.GeoHelpers
rule "Get by Distance"
salience 10
when
    $allLocations: LocationContainer()
    $person: Person()
    $loc: TopLocation() from $allLocations.getAllLocations()
then
    double distance = GeoHelpers.getInstance().getHaversineInMiles($person.getLat(), $person.getLon(), $loc.getLat(), $loc.getLon());
    System.out.println($loc.getTitle() + " -- distance in miles to person: " + distance); 
end;
```

It doesn't - by far - do, what I want to achieve ... but perhaps you can give some hints ...

So, first of all I think that I need to invoke my static java method (which just calculates the distance between two given points) in the LHS of the rule, but as soon as I (try to) do that, it fails compiling the rule. Then I need to use the result of $dist to determine, if that current entry needs to be put into the new list (how can I a.) create a new list and b.) put the current entry into that?) ... and then, the next logical step would be creating a new rule "Get by Location Title" with a higher salience and use the new filtered list. So that in the end, when I'm back on the java side, I can grab all lists from the Working Memory and do further stuff with them.

Yes, I know, my questions might be pretty n00b-ish ... but I couldn't find anything from which I could derive my use-case.

However, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address this point by point rather than try and provide a "complete" solution. You'll have to decide what to use.

First, there may be a good reason for keeping all locations in a container class that is a single fact but, generally, rules are easier to write if the container elements themselves are facts.

```
rule "person and location"
when
    $p: Person()
    $l: TopLocation(...)
    ...
```

(Of course, you can stick with the `from` clause.)

To select a location with a certain property in combination with a Person: use any boolean expression as a constraint or an eval pattern. If the expression involves some static Java function, import it (as you would in Java) or implement it as a DRL function. I'll illustrate this as a combination of all three.

```
import com.acme.helper.GeoHelpers
function double dist( Person p, TopLocation t ){
    double d =
      GeoHelpers.getInstance().getHaversineInMiles(p.getLat(), p.getLon(),
                                                   t.getLat(), t.getLon());
}

rule "p & l closer than"
when
    $p: Person()
    $l: TopLocation( dist($p,$l) < 100.0 )
    ...
```

For filtering the locations by more criteria you could use an additional rule where the locations meeting the required "title" are selected, but that would need to keep track of the locations selected by distance. To do without, simply add the "title" constraint to the rule:

```
 rule "p & l: Hotel closer than 100"
 when
    $p: Person()
    $l: TopLocation( dist($p,$l) < 100.0,
                     title == "Hotel" )
    ...
```

And so on.

You'll say that this rule is just for a single selection use case - what if the distance is different or you are looking for book stores?

You can use a parameter block fact for defining the literals.

```
rule "p & l, X loc closer than D"
when
    Param( $d: distance, $t: title )
    $p: Person()
    $l: TopLocation( dist($p,$l) < $d, title == $t )
    ...
```

You might say that this is very nice but what if the combination of selection criteria itself varies, and not just the values? Then, of course, it may indeed be better to have separate rules, each selecting locations by a single criterion. With this, providing the paramters can be combined with selecting the appropriate rule, which can be done by multiple Param subclasses. An additional problem arises: how to keep track of the selection set. For this we may have to use another auxiliary fact, let's call it `ResultSet`. Assuming that distance is always a criterion, we can write rules such as

```
rule "p & l, closer than D"
when
    $dp: DistParam( $v: distance )
    $p: Person()
    $l: ArrayList() from 
        collect( $l: TopLocation( dist($p,$l) < $v )
then
    retract( $dp );
    insert( new ResultSet( $l ) );
end

rule "p & l, filter by title"
when
    $t: TitleParam( $v: title )
    $r: ResultSet( $s: result )
    $l: ArrayList() from 
        collect( $l: TopLocation( title == $v ) from $s
then
    retract( $t );
    modify( $r ){ setResult($l) }
end
```

Now it's easy to have an arbitrary selection of criteria, with values derived from the current search. - You may retrieve the `ResultSet` using the API after `fireAllRules` has returned, or write another rule to process and retract it.

I recommend that you study the available literature.